# What were Jordan's views on Global Warming?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Eye of the World*, the first novel in The Wheel of Time saga, Robert Jordan, the author, writes:

> The sun was a swollen, red blood ball, more fiery than the hottest day of summer and bright enough to sear his eyes. But it stood stark against the leaden cauldron of a sky where clouds of sharp blacks and silver roiled and boiled on every horizon. For all the swirling clouds, though, no breath of breeze stirred across the land, and despite the sullen sun the air burned cold like the depths of winter.

This might as well describe some of the extreme weather events that science has warned of over the past few decades. Is there any indication that Jordan was interested in Global Warming and what was his views on this?

Comment: Interesting idea. Certainly, global warming was well-known by that point. If this excerpt is supposed to represent the Age of Legends or the Time of Madness, I could well believe that Jordan is making a reference to that. Is that the case?

Comment: When I looked at the title, the first thing that came to mind was Jordan Peterson

Comment: I did not downvote your question before, because it contributed to the site. But given that you think it makes sense to go on some unrelated rant in your question, I will indeed downvote it. Frankly, I can't even make heads or tails of your last sentence. "No," you don't think Jordan's statements are indicative of prejudice? Also, I have edited your answer to remove the off-topic political content and unmotivated imprecations against other users. Frankly, I think you provide a useful counterbalance to certain other views, but if you really want to get banned, of course feel free to revert.

Comment: Actually, it's really a bit bizarre that my criticism of Robert Jordan's arguably neo-colonialist influenced beliefs is what made you go off on that *particular* rant, but whatever puts your caprine entity in hydrostatic equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

It is of course unclear whether Jordan's views on climate change influenced the particular depiction mentioned in the question. While not implausible—the phenomenon itself *was* talked about beyond the scientific community in late 1980s—there are certainly other possibilities. Most notably, a swollen red sun recalls, more than warming caused by the greenhouse effect, the end stage of many stars' life cycles. This is the same sort of portrayal that appeared in *The Last Battle* by C.S. Lewis, or even in *The Time Machine* by H.G. Wells. These portrayals actually postdate the first theoretical scientific descriptions of the greenhouse effect at the atmospheric level, but they certainly predate general knowledge of climate change. In fact, I do not know if red giants as older stars were known at the time Wells wrote *The Time Machine*, so he might have been influenced by the fact that a setting sun appears large and red.

However, regardless of whether these ideas influenced the author or not, the question of what his personal opinions were is interesting, and by an extraordinary stroke of luck, we do have some information about Robert Jordan's personal views, which are generally on-topic under our "fan information" questions. This is from an interview that he gave in 2000, [transcribed here.](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27military%27) The questions appear to have been largely translated from Russian.

> INTERVIEW: Sep, 2000 Wanderer Fantasy Convention - "Wars of the
> Future" with Robert Jordan (Translated)
>
> QUESTION You mean something
> like global warming?
>
> ROBERT JORDAN Climate change in the future makes me more than worried,
> even if one considers only the favorable scenario. If we consider the
> worst, then I’m terrified. They can be avoided, but... The nations of
> the Third World demand exclusive rights in the fight against global
> warming, because, if you follow their logic, everything that happens
> is a conspiracy against them personally, and they should have a chance
> to become equal to the developed world. If our leaders grant them
> these rights, in the coming century, China will be the main polluter
> of the environment and the major contributor to global warming on
> Earth, but who can stop them? So the climate becomes a wild card in
> the total war game. Which of the nations will suddenly discover that
> they have too little land to feed themselves, and decide to take land
> from their neighbors? Which nation, upset by the changes in climate
> that have been caused by the attempt to become equal with the
> civilized world, will go down the ancient path of resolving internal
> conflict, i.e. foreign war?
>
> We believe that we can limit the future of war—the length, the amount
> of bloodshed, the site of action—but can we really? Can we at least
> know where the next war will come from, or who will be our new enemy?
> Today in the heart of Africa, in Congo, there are seven tribes and the
> three rebel groups engaged in what many call the "First World War in
> Africa." The United Nations are trying to stop the conflict, but
> without visible results. You can try to believe that this war is far
> away or that it involves only a third world country or that this war
> doesn’t affect us, but history has seen cases, where a miniscule
> conflict turned into a large-scale war. The fire of the First World
> War started from a single spark, but who could believe that everything
> starts with the Serbian attempt to gain independence from
> Austria-Hungary? Any "reasonable" person of that time would say that
> this is not enough to spark the fire.

What I gather this about his opinions:

- He thought that global warming was definitely real and a serious threat.
- He believed that it could lead to conflicts.
- He thought that climate change could be avoided, but was pessimistic about the probability of success, mainly blaming developing countries.
- And, although this is not directly related to his beliefs about climate change,  I note that he had some inaccurate or downright prejudiced beliefs about countries that he would have characterized as belonging to the "Third World", contrasting them in a rather retrograde fashion with the "civilized world," suggesting that their rights would need to be "granted" by said world, and attributing greenhouse gas emissions largely to their desire for economic growth. Also, they called the Second Congo War "Africa's World War," not "The First World War in Africa" but that is perhaps nitpicking.